# Concentration of maxima of a random polynomial with Rademacher coefficients

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, stochastic-processes

Let $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ be independent Rademacher random variables (i.e. $\mathbb{P}(X_i=\pm 1)=1/2$). Consider the random polynomial $$P_{n}(t)=c+X_{1}t+X_2t^2+\cdots+X_{n}t^n.$$

Is it well known how to get good upper bounds on probabilities of type
$$\mathbb{P}(|\max_{t\in [0,x]}|P_{n}(t)|-\mathbb{E}\max_{t\in [0,x]}|P_{n}(t)||>y)?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theorem 5.3.2 in [Talagrand's book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-54075-2) states the following (using here somewhat different notations):

> Let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ be independent Rademacher random variables. Let $U$ be a subset of the closed ball $B(u_0,s)$ in $\ell^2$ centered at some $u_0\in\ell^2$ and of some radius $s>0$. Let 
>   $$S:=\sup_{u\in U}\Big(c(u)+\sum_{i\ge1}u_iX_i\Big),$$
>   where $c\colon U\to\mathbb R$. Then 
>   $$P(|S-ES|\ge y)\le C\exp\Big(-\frac{y^2}{Cs^2}\Big) $$
>   for some universal real constant $C>0$ and all real $y>0$.
>
> If $ES$ in the latter display is replaced by the median of $S$, then $C$ may be replaced by $4$.

Take now any real 
$$s\ge\inf_{u\in\mathbb R^n}\max_{t\in[0,x]}\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^n(u_j-t^j)^2}.$$
Then, by the above statement, the probability in question is bounded from above by $ C\exp\Big(-\dfrac{y^2}{Cs^2}\Big)$. In particular, here one may take $s=\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^n x^{2j}}$.

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer!